# Casting an open generic at runtime in c#

Tags: c#, generics, structuremap

I have a simple generic error handler `IErrorHandler<T>` where `T` is an exception.  I'm using structuremap to get the concrete implementation of the handler based on the exception raised in Application_Error.  So here is the code I use to get the handler.

```
var exceptionType = ex.GetType();
var handlerType = typeof(IErrorHandler<>).MakeGenericType(exceptionType);

var handler = IoCContainer.GetInstance(handlerType); // this returns an object
```

At this point, Structuremap has returned the correct implementation.  But handler is an object, so I can't call any functions that the interface has.  I can use reflection to find the Handle method, but that's fragile.

```
var handle = handlerType.GetMethod("Handle");
handle.Invoke(handler, new[] {ex});
```

Is there a better way to cast an open generic when the type the generic is using is only known at runtime?

Comment: Is the `Handle` method itself generic?

Comment: That´s the drawback on using reflection. There´s no way to get a *compile*-time-type, you´re allways stuck on `object`. You can only cast to some non-generic base-interface that your generic ones derives from.

Answer (score 3):

That´s the drawback on using reflection. There´s no way to get a *compile*-time-type, when you provide the type-parameter at *runtime*. Thus you´re allways stuck on `object`. You can only cast to some non-generic base-interface that your generic ones derives from. Define your `Handle`-method there instead:

```
interface IErrorHandler
{
    void Handle(Exception e);
}
interface IErrorHandler<T> where T: Exception { }
```

Now you can use this:

```
var exceptionType = ex.GetType();
var handlerType = typeof(IErrorHandler<>).MakeGenericType(exceptionType);

var handler = (IErrorHandler) IoCContainer.GetInstance(handlerType); /
handler.Handle(ex);
```

You could also add a generic method to your generic interface. Now all classes should also implement that method, whereas calls to the non-generic version should be re-directed to the generic one.

```
class MyClass<T> : IErrorHandler<T> where T: Exception
{
    void Handle(Exception e) { this.Handle((T)e); }
    void Handle<T>(T e { /* your code here */ }
}
```

Doing this will however not prevent you from a caller casting your instance to the non-generic interface and passing *any* exception to it. This will still yield in an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Technicality: You forgot the argument in `Handle()`

Comment: Making the interfaces like that means that the exception passed into the handler doesn't necessarily have to be of type `T`.  Not really a problem per se, but it does lessen the value in having the generic.

Comment: @Amy I leave it open to the OP to also add a type-safe implementation within the generic interface. But even then if we casted to the non-generic version we could supply another exception-type, so that´s not a real gain.